# Custom HTMLParser with regex not returning correctly

Tags: regex, python-2.7, html-parsing

I'm working on a program that is scraping some information from an HTML-file based on different regex expressions. I've encountered an error with the following code

My HTMLParser subclass:

```
class MyHtmlParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.title = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        Result = re.search(r'ANMELDELSE .*(?=</b>)',d)
        if Result:
            self.title.append(Result.group(0))
    def return_data(self):
        return self.title
```

Running the code:

```
with open(r'....', "r") as f: #correct path to local test.html
    page = f.read()
parser.feed(page)
parser.return_data()
```

Now the HTML file is really messy and in Norwegian, but here is a subset that should trigger this

```
<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Sak 428/18-123, 03.09.2018 </span></p>
<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><b>&nbsp;</b></p>
<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><b>ANMELDELSE FOR TRAKASSERING</b></p>
```

This should select "ANMELDELSE FOR TRAKASSERING" and it does in  both https://regex101.com/ and in https://regexr.com/, but when executing the code, all I get printed is an empty list. The code has worked with previous regex calls, so I'm a bit lost.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: If I were to use a regex here, I'd use something close to `r'ANMELDELSE[^<>]*`. Are you sure the space there is not a non-breaking space?

Comment: What kind of object is passed in as `d` when you call `handle_data(self, d)`?

Comment: This really helped @WiktorStribiżew! Do you mind clarifying what you mean by non-breaking space? I was very confused when both websites I tried it on gave me the correct answer..

Comment: It is a [`\u00A0` char](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%A0), very similar to a regular space.

Comment: That was probably it, it seems to work now! Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted your text has `ANMELDELSE` only in some text node, you may grab it using

```
r'ANMELDELSE[^<>]*'
```

Your original pattern contains a literal regular space (`\x20`). Instead of that space, a [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm) is often used to make sure the next word stays on the same line in text editors/viewers.

To match it, you could use `\s` and pass `re.U` modifier (it is required as you are using Python 2.7) to your `re.search` method, but since you want to match up to the end of the tag, just use a negated character class `[^<>]*`,  any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`.